# check the limited checkbox on single click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 var max_limit = 3;
// only 3 checkboxes are allowed manually check checkboxes
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('input:checkbox[name="chkBox"]').on('change', function (e) {
            if ($('input:checkbox[name="chkBox"]:checked').length > 3) {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                alert("Only 3 selections are allowed");
            }
        });
        
     
  // for select 3 i tried below code but it is not working
  var rowCount = $("#example tr").length;
            if(rowCount < max_limit)
            {
                max_limit = rowCount;
            }
           
            for(var i=1; i <= max_limit; i++){
                $('input:checkbox[name="chkBox"]').index(i).prop('checked', this.checked); 
                    
                 
            }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th class="vertalign">Select 3 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="selectAllChkBox" id="selectAllChkBox">     
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="cat"  name="chkBox"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="dog"  name="chkBox"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cow</td>
    <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="cow"  name="chkBox"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="mouse"  name="chkBox"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Goat</td>
    <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="goat"  name="chkBox"></td>
  </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a table of items and in each row there is a checkbox. I don't want to permit user to select all of the checkboxes at a time. So instead of select All option i provided select 3. after clicking on it first 3 items should be selected automatically.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: What is a "*limited checkbox*"? "*...on clicking select 3*" - is that one element (what type of element), or three individual elements? Please: we know nothing about what you're doing, except for the parts you explain to us, we're not trying to be obtuse but until you explain yourself we can't help you, because we don't know what you're working with or what you're trying to achieve. Take a look at both the "*[mcve]*" and the "*[ask]*" guidance, then update your question with an [edit].

Comment: I have a table of items and in each row there is a checkbox. I don't want to permit user to select all of the checkboxes at a time. So instead of select All option i provided select 3. after clicking on it first 3 items should be selected automatically.

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML to the question, along with your best attempts at JavaScript (including jQuery, if that's what you're working with); and add the details and explanation there, also. Comments aren't permanent here on [SO], and it's information that needs to be in the question for easy reference for those that may try to answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It works in your code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```js
let items = $("input[name=chkBox]");

      $("#selectAllChkBox").change(function (e) {
        if ($("#selectAllChkBox").is(':checked')) {
          for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $(items[i]).prop('checked', true);
          }
        } else {
          $("input[name=chkBox]").prop('checked', false);
        }
      });

      $(items).change(function (e) {
        let current_item = e.target;

        let checked_items = $("input[name=chkBox]:checked");
        if (checked_items.length > 3) {
          alert('You can only select three items!');
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Animal</th>
          <th class="vertalign">Select 3 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="selectAllChkBox" id="selectAllChkBox">
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Cat</td>
          <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="cat" name="chkBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dog</td>
          <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="dog" name="chkBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cow</td>
          <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="cow" name="chkBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mouse</td>
          <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="mouse" name="chkBox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Goat</td>
          <td class="vertalign" rowspan="5"><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" value="goat" name="chkBox"></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: If it is working fine then you can mark this answer as the accepted answer.